# How can I create an ASP.NET Web API 2 using stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures

How can I create an ASP.NET Web API using Entity Framework? I created Db Connection using Entity Framework, I added the table and stored procedures.

I import the stored procedures in the `.edmx` diagram:

[image]

Model looks like

```
namespace EmployeeInformationDatabase.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class spGetEmployeees_Result
    {
        [Key]
        public int Employee_Number { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string User_logon_Name { get; set; }
        public string Employee_Display_Name { get; set; }
        public string Employee_Type { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Active { get; set; }
        public string Is_Supervisor { get; set; }
        public string index_no { get; set; }
        public string Noname { get; set; }
        public string position { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and my controller Looks Like

```
using EmployeeInformationDatabase.Models;

namespace EmployeeInformationDatabase.Controllers
{
    public class spGetEmployeees_ResultController : ApiController
    {
        private EmployeeEntities db = new EmployeeEntities();

        // GET: api/spGetEmployeees_Result
        public IQueryable<spGetEmployeees_Result> GetspGetEmployeees_Result()
        {
            return db.spGetEmployeees_Result;
        }
    }
}
```

but I get this when I run the Web API from `http://localhost:55198/api/spGetEmployeees_Result`:

[image]